# iOS RestKit POST unmodified JSON string

Tags: ios, json, post, restkit-0.20

I have a special need to send a pre-formatted JSON string to the server. Due to the server using older Microsoft technology the JSON elements MUST be in a certain order. If I use the standard JSON processing of RestKit the JSON elements come from a dictionary and are added in hash order. Sadly this will not work for this one special case.

How can I send a pre-formatted JSON string instead of an NSDictionary that is converted to a JSON string with RestKit 0.2x?

Here is the code for the request using NSDictionary

```
RKObjectManager *objectManager = self.createObjectManager;
RKObjectMapping *requestMapping =  [EssenceRequest.objectMapping inverseMapping];

[objectManager addRequestDescriptor:[RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping
                                                                          objectClass:EssenceRequest.class
                                                                          rootKeyPath:nil
                                                                               method:RKRequestMethodPOST]];
RKObjectMapping *responseMapping = EssenceRoot.objectMapping;

RKResponseDescriptor* essenceResponse = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:responseMapping
                                                                                     method:RKRequestMethodPOST
                                                                                pathPattern:nil
                                                                                    keyPath:nil
                                                                                statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:essenceResponse];

EssenceRequest *dataObject = [[EssenceRequest alloc] initWithContextAndHandle:uniqueHandle essenceHandle:essenceHandle];

[objectManager postObject:dataObject
                     path:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@GetEssences", Connection.apiPrefix, Connection.svcMedia, Connection.jsonSecure]
               parameters:nil
                  success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    [serverResponseDelegate serverResponseSuccess:operation mappingResult:mappingResult ];
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    [serverResponseDelegate serverResponseFailure:operation error:error];
}];
```

The EssenceRequest

```
- (id)initWithContextAndHandle:(NSString *)uniqueHandle essenceHandle:(NSString *)essenceUH;
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        _request = @{
                @"__type" : @"SpecificEssenceLocationRequest:#Messaging.Media",
                @"Action" : @"1",
                @"ContextUH" : uniqueHandle,
                @"EssenceUH" : essenceUH
        };
    }
    return self;
}

+ (RKObjectMapping*)objectMapping
{
    RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:EssenceRequest.class];

    [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
            @"request": @"request"
    }];

    return mapping;
}
```

The "__type" item must be the first time in the JSON request body. Right now with it being in a dictionary it shows up later in the body when the dictionary is converted to a JSON string.

I know this is poor JSON handling on the server. They will fix it at some point and not require the __type any more but for now I need to send it as needed. I was able to do this in my Android code so I know the request will work once I have the NSString formatted.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: following answer is just my own opinion / suggestion.

Use `+[RKMimeTypeSerialization unregisterClass:[RKNSJSONSerialization class]]` to unregister default RestKit json serialization class. Then write your own class with "hacked" keys order. Register it through `+[RKMimeTypeSerialization registerClass:[RKMYJSONSerialization class] forMINEType:RKMIMETypeJSON]`

This way your won't change any API's - just "inject" your code into serialization/deserialization mechanism (and this is what you actually need).

The default implementation of RKNSJSONSerialization is quite simple:

```
+ (id)objectFromData:(NSData *)data error:(NSError **)error
{
    return [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:error];
}

+ (NSData *)dataFromObject:(id)object error:(NSError **)error
{
    return [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:object options:0 error:error];
}
```

I think, you can go further yourself and write your own, based, of course on NSJSONSerialization or some another JSON serialization mechanism.

Comment: This might be pointing me in the right direction but I was hoping to only affect the request body for this one call to the server. All the other calls work just fine with standard JSON serialization.

Any way to just affect [objectManager postObject:dataObject with a different dataObject type?

Comment: If you need just one request for this, you may consider using old good AFHTTPRequestOperation for it. No RestKit (You say, it's temporary backend issue, eh? ;) )

Comment: May have to go that direction. I was really liking the success / failure pattern for RestKit. This one request sure is a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Taking Petro's answer a step further. This solution will maintain the functionality of all other requests.

After implementation you can wrap any JSON string in a `SPRawJSON` to send it as raw JSON for any request.

**SPJSONSerialization.h**

```
#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>

@interface SPRawJSON : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *json;
-(instancetype)initWithJSON:(NSString*)json;
+(RKObjectMapping*)mapping;
@end

@interface SPJSONSerialization : NSObject <RKSerialization>

@end
```

**SPJSONSerialization.m**

```
#import "SPJSONSerialization.h"

@implementation SPRawJSON

-(instancetype)initWithJSON:(NSString*)json
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _json = json;
    }
    return self;
}

+(RKObjectMapping*)mapping {
    RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[SPRawJSON class]];
    [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"rawJSON": @"self" }];
    return mapping;
}
@end

@implementation SPJSONSerialization

+ (id)objectFromData:(NSData *)data error:(NSError **)error {
    return [RKNSJSONSerialization objectFromData:data error:error];
}

+ (NSData *)dataFromObject:(id)object error:(NSError **)error {
    if ([object isKindOfClass:NSDictionary.class]) {
        NSDictionary *dict = object;
        id rawJSONObj = dict[@"rawJSON"];
        if (rawJSONObj && [rawJSONObj isKindOfClass:SPRawJSON.class]) {
            return [[(SPRawJSON*)rawJSONObj json] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        }
    }
    return [RKNSJSONSerialization dataFromObject:object error:error];
}

@end
```

**Registering the mapping**

```
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
// Make requests bodies be sent as JSON
objectManager.requestSerializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;

// Add inverse mapping for the request
RKRequestDescriptor *descriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:[SPRawJSON mapping].inverseMapping objectClass:[SPRawJSON class] rootKeyPath:nil method:RKRequestMethodPOST];
[objectManager addRequestDescriptor:descriptor];
```

**Registering the JSON Serializer**

```
// Replace standard JSON Serializer with our custom one that accepts raw json strings as well (SPRawJSON)
let currentJSONSerializer = RKMIMETypeSerialization.serializationClass(forMIMEType: RKMIMETypeJSON)
RKMIMETypeSerialization.unregisterClass(currentJSONSerializer)
RKMIMETypeSerialization.registerClass(SPJSONSerialization.self, forMIMEType: RKMIMETypeJSON)
```

**Example code for sending request**

```
NSString *myJSON = @"{\"exampleKey\": \"Example value\"}";
SPRawJSON *rawJSON = [[SPRawJSON alloc] initWithJSON:myJSON];
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
[objectManager postObject:rawJSON path:@"foo/bar" parameters:nil success: ... failure: ...]
```

Notice that the mapping only maps `POST` requests, so if you want it to work for `PUT`, etc, you need to map that as well.